# Checkstyle Suppression For Just Annotations

Tags: annotations, checkstyle

Is there a way you can suppress a checkstyle rule only for the annotations in a file. Example I am getting a magic number in my annotation and I want to suppress magic number rule but only for the annotation not the whole file.

Comment: Did you check http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the `ignoreAnnotation` parameter to true in order to do that.

See documentation [here](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#MagicNumber).